# Kotlin KDoc: Documentation?

Tags: kotlin, kdoc, kotlin-dokka

I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604143/kotlin-auto-documentation-tools), [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/Kotlin/Kotlin+Doc) and [there](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/tools/kdoc) references to KDoc, the JavaDoc utility equivalent for Kotlin.

However, I cannot find any documentation on how to use it, let alone how to customize it or integrate it in Maven or Gradle.

I know the [Kotlin API doc](http://jetbrains.github.io/kotlin/versions/snapshot/apidocs/) is generated using KDoc since the page source has the following HTML comment: `<!-- Generated by kdoc on Sun Jul 06 20:27:33 UTC 2014 -->`

So, is there any documentation I can refer to as to how to use KDoc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Kdoc was put on the back burner in favour of Dokka.
https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka

Source: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/458339;jsessionid=B2038D70DCC9004181B20D6D4EA2B2A3

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. KDoc still exists; it was just changed. Dokka is just the tool that generates the HTML documentation from the KDoc. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html