# Kotlin: which format to use for documentation?

Tags: markdown, kotlin

According to [Kotlin KDoc: Documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527838/kotlin-kdoc-documentation) and https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/458339, KDoc is stalled, and there is another documentation processing engine being developed, but it is not ready yet.

**Question**: as of now, is there any agreed format of documentation which will be fully supported by doc generator and by Kotlin plugin for IDEA?

P.S. Just don't want to rewrite docs I've been written so far (in Markdown).

Comment: According to this commit https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/853fce4b7191e52ba6277972851e731c0c2d1802 markdown will be supported shortly, maybe in the next milestone release.

Comment: Looks like it's going that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The just published M11 release of Kotlin officially supports a new documentation format based on a combination of Markdown and JavaDoc. You can find the full documentation for it [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html).

The new documentation generation tool will be officially released in a very short while. Right now it's available in a Git repository [here](https://github.com/orangy/dokka).