# What is the correct name for Kotlin inline documentation?

Tags: kotlin, kdoc, kotlin-dokka

Since KDoc documentation generation engine is [abandoned in favor of Dokka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28534725/1542343), should Kotlin documentation be referred to as "KDoc comments", or as "Dokka comments"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html), KDoc is the language used to write Kotlin documentation comments. Dokka is a tool that understands KDoc comments in Kotlin files and Javadoc comments in Java files, and generates documentation from them. Therefore, "KDoc comments" is the correct term to use.